# can we validate multiple functions inside if condition with AND operator using java script is there any other way to check multiple functions true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement, return-value

I have added these functions and need return something based which function is returning true but it is not working.

```
//this is function1/
function A() {
  return true;
}

function B() {
  return true;
}

function C() {
  if ({
      {
        var -customJS - page_type_lookup
      }
    } === 'product') {
    var config = document.querySelector('#product-content > div.product-variations.clearfix > div.attribute.variant-dropdown > div.attribute-values-section > div.label.va-navSectionalOrientation').innerText;
    if (config.includes('Sectional Orientation')) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
if (A() === true && B() === true && C() === true) {
  return 'A+ Content, RTA Product, Sectional Configurator';
} else if (A() === true && B() === true) {
  return 'A+ Content, RTA Product';

} else if (B() === true && C() === true) {
  return 'RTA Product, Sectional Configurator';
} else if (C() === true && A() === true) {
  return 'Sectional Configurator, A+ Content';
} else if (A() === true) {
  return 'A+ Content';
} else if (B() === true) {
  return 'RTA Product';
} else {
  return 'Sectional Configurator';
}
}
```

Comment: The problem is not for *how* to use an AND. It's more that the code has syntax errors.

Comment: Start by checking what the browser console has to say, and fix your syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one function and a data set which reflects the wanted value of each flag, you could take an array for the functions retun values and another for the strings which are filterd and joined for the result.

```
const
    flags = [a(), b(), c()],
    result = ['A+ Content', 'RTA Product', 'Sectional Configurator']
        .filter((_, i) => flags[i])
        .join(', ');
```

Comment: thank you so much could you please elaborate the code i am new to the javascript

Comment: OMG, I can read your post (answer). Unbelievable :)